# .Net UpdatePanel and javascript disabled

Tags: .net, ajax, forms, updatepanel, multipartform-data

This may sound, or actually be, a stupid question but I need to find the best way to proceed with a project I am on. I have a multipage webform, using the multiview control. That multiview is in an updatepanel control, and everything works great so far.

My question is about users with javascript disabled. What I have noticed is that in this scenario, when a user clicks the button to go to the next page, I am just left with a normal multi page form, where the page causes a postback, the page refreshes, and the user is on the next page. So basically it looks like the updatepanel is smart enough to fall back to just normal post backs.

Is this supposed to be the case for anything in an updatepanel? I ask because within the updatepanel I have several panels that get turned on and off based on other selections. For example if a user selects they are outside of the US, I show additional panels for international info. That is not happening when javascript is disabled.

If this is the way it is supposed to work I'll just have to figure something out for users with javascript disabled.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET components should automatically handle situations where JavaScript is disabled.  However, in the case of the panels within the update panel, if you are using JavaScript to refresh them or change them, this will obviously not work.  (Since you have the AJAX tag, I am assuming you are using JavaScript here.)

Of course, one thing to consider is your users.  Most people browse the web with JavaScript on.  This may be a case you don't need to support other than saying, "Please enable JavaScript."