# ASP.NET web forms: UpdatePanel no-js fallback for AutoPostback?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, autopostback

I have an `UpdatePanel` which I've decided to try out, and I assumed that all of its behaviors would be taken care of by the asp.net mechanism when javascript is turned off. One of the behaviors is doing some UI changes when a dropdownlist or checkbox are changed. Those changes are revealing sections of the form or changing the Text of some `<asp:Label>` controls. When JS is enabled, my `AutoPostback="true"` attribute on the checkbox makes its change event update the form like it needs to be. However when the JS is not enabled, it does nothing - and I'd like it to resume the kind of behavior it had before I started using the `UpdatePanel` - which is to refresh the page each time with updated server data. Are there any tweaks one can make to the `UpdatePanel` properties to achieve this kind of fallback solution?

*(no, this isn't a real requirement for the job at hand, but I expected the asp.net's server controls would auto-solve this kind of issue in the first place, so I'd like to know if there's some way.)*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.Net UpdatePanel and javascript disabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258063/net-updatepanel-and-javascript-disabled)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the ASP.net autopostback attribute and functionality are not working when you disable JavaScript is that it actually utilizes JavaScript code to perform its functions.
Specifically speaking it generates the following JavaScript code:

a. A Java script method with name

```
__doPostBack (eventtarget, eventargument)
```

b. Two Hidden variables with name `__EVENTTARGET` and

```
__EVENTARGUMENT
```

c. `OnChange` JavaScript event to the control

If you use your browser's debugger and search for those you will see how they are implemented.
Here is a good resource that goes into further details:
http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/189-AutoPostBack-What-How-works.aspx

The postback basically resubmits a page request but retains the viewstate the update panel controls which sections get updated.

To answer your question there is no way to accomplish AJAX type functionality without a enabling Javascript

Comment: Thank you, but I wish they had made it work, or enabled a setting to have the contents inside an UpdatePanel to act on postback instructions such as they would when written outside of the UpdatePanel. This would extend functionality for all kinds of marginal devices and make it so there won't have to be special code for anything like that. I suppose there are ways to work around this if someone really had to.